# Using a more advance search query in http GET request

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking for a more advanced way to structure a query related to a http GET request

For example, 
instead of

```
?quantity=5&delivery_date_min=&delivery_date_max=20200520&created_from=20191212&crated_to&name=productname
```

have

```
q=quantity:5 delivery_date<=20200520 created_from>=20191212 name:"product name"
```

My question is
- is there already a standard relating these types of queries and is it

Closest thing to this query I came across is Lucene query syntax, but since I am using asp.net core and c# I am not sure is there an alternative terminology and approach for c#, or is it solely up to an individual to structure and parse these type of queries?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://www.odata.org/ ?

Comment: Azure search docs cloud be useful for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-simple-examples

Answer (score 0):

> Is there already a standard relating these types of queries

There are a few query languages that "sit on top of REST" to help people create more complex queries, the two that comes to mind straight away are

OData - https://www.odata.org/

To quote their documentation page

> OData has been standardized by OASIS and approved as an ISO/IEC International Standard.

Their queries look something like this:

```
serviceRoot/People('russellwhyte')/Trips(1003)/PlanItems(21)/Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.Flight
```

From what I remember this actually originates from Microsoft, and is definately worth checking out

GraphQL - https://graphql.org/

Open standard developed by the people at facebook

example query:

```
{
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height
  }
}
```

This has a few libraries that have c# support: https://graphql.org/code/#c-net

**Edit**
One thing I will say about the framworkds I have talked about here, they are very opinionated about how you should be querying/returning your data, this can be advantageous or disadvantageous, it's probably worth doing a good amount of research about both of them before committing to either.